# Magento Toolbar -> Limit

Tags: magento, limit, toolbar, categories, pager

does anyone know how to (re)code the limiter of a certain category to display href links instead of the drop down field?

I mean this:
http://cl.ly/2T2i2T2g0k3n0i2N0b2c

and i want to recode it to:
http://cl.ly/2O1e0L1c1i24361t3Z3v

Just want to transform the drop down to some simple html links but...

I', fully capable to do it but I'm not an expert in Magento and I just think that i can't hardlink it like www.store.com/category.html?limit=12 in the source code. I need an function that returns me the category url.

Does anyone know how to code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy.

Go to /app/design/frontend/[your-interface]/[your-theme]/template/page/html/pager.phtml and replace this code:

```
    <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
            <?php echo $_limit ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
```

whith this:

```
    <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"><?php echo $_limit ?></a> &nbsp;
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
```

Comment: it wasn exactly the location you described (it was catalog/list/toolbar.phtml in my case)but this code works perfectly. THANK YOU!

Comment: That's because you need to create the file yourself inside that folder. It exists in base, but not your theme.